# Django FormView dispatch method is called, even though UserPassesTestMixin's test_func() has returned False

Tags: python, django, authentication, mixins

I have a class based form view that implements both LoginRequiredMixin and UserPassesTestMixin

```
class BookingCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, FormView):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

    def test_func(self):
        return is_customer(self.request.user)
```

When I visit the page while logged in as a user that fails the test_func, instead of getting a 404, as a result of a failed test_func, the code in my view's dispatch method is executing...

Shouldn't the test_func() be called before dispatch() ? and if the result of test_func() is False, shouldn't view rendering stop at this point?

Comment: You didn't show the rest of the dispatch code, but you have to call `super().dispatch()` for the `UserPassesTestMixin` to trigger

Comment: As mentioned by @BrianDestura you need to call `super().dispatch()`, this is because both `LoginRequiredMixin` and `UserPassesTestMixin` are overriding that and using it as their entrypoint, if you don't call super they will never be used.

Comment: The final line of my dispatch method returned a call to super().dispatch(), as follows:

return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

On your advice, i tried making an immediate call to super().dispatch() as the first line in my dispatch() method. Despite doing this, the rest of the dispatch method is executing, as opposed to a 404 being raised by the test_func()...

Answer (score 0):

I think presented code is not enough to understanding what are you do wrong.
But I guess your mixin's code was written wrong.

This is how I would write this one.

```
class SomeView(SomeDispatchMixin, ...)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.test_user(request.user):
            ...    # raise some http error or return http response with some error code
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

class SomeDispatchMixin:
    def test_user(user):
        ...    # Some logic to test an user
```